# SFTP connection using Reflection Client

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, private-key

I am trying to establish SFTP connection using Reflection Client by passing a private key as a parameter. Can any one help with the connection Code.

FTP.Open("test.rebex.net", "demo", "password", "", 22, isTrue);

How to pass the private key and authenticate the connection. How can we implement this in C#.net

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://www.attachmate.com/documentation/reflection-desktop-v16-1/rdesktop-guide/data/secure_shell_r200x_connect_pr.htm) help? SFTP is basically FTP over a SSH tunnel.